# Why doesn't it look like -Xms and -Xmx are doing anything to Java's memory usage in Windows?

Tags: java, jvm

I am running this version of Java:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

I am running this on a Windows 2008 R2 64-bit server on Amazon EC2, in an m1.large instance that has 7.5GB of memory.

When I start my Java app, I am using this command line:

```
java -Xms6G -Xmx6G -server -jar start.jar
```

My intent is to have Java reserve 6GB for it's heap, so that when my application runs, it will be able to load its entire dataset into memory.

However, when I start the app, I only see 1.3GB of memory used in Task Manager?

Comment: if you see `1.3GB` is being used, then what is wrong? If you get Heap size exception with `1.3GB`usage, then for me the question makes sense

Comment: @elbek I requested 6G, so to see only 1.3G reserved is a problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is you're looking at the default memory column shown in Task Manager, which is "Memory - Private Working Set." This doesn't reflect what is actually reserved for use.

In Task Manager, go to the View menu and choose Select Columns. Add the "Memory - Commit Size" column. You should see this column reflects the reserved heap size from Java. In my tests, it shows around 6.6GB committed for a commandline of -Xms6G.

[Here is Microsoft's page that explains what each column means.](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/What-do-the-Task-Manager-memory-columns-mean)

"**Memory - Private Working Set:** Subset of working set that specifically describes the amount of memory a process is using that cannot be shared by other processes."

"**Memory - Commit Size:** Amount of virtual memory that is reserved for use by a process."